# MYSQL- finding the different values in a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table containing id, model and date. I need to create a query to find or tag the different  model for a particular id. any idea how to sort this out. thank you in advance.

**Sample table and script:**

```
select t1.id, t1.item, t1.auditdate -- , t2.itembuild as diff 
from temptable_test t1
inner join temptable_test t2
on t1.id = t2.id -- and t1.item <> t2.item
where t1.item <> t2.item
group by  t1.id, t1.item , t1.auditdate;

drop table if exists temptable_test;
create table temptable_test
(
        id VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
        item VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,   
        auditdate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL 
);

insert into temptable_test(id,item,auditdate)
values ('111111111111','GRAY','2021-06-10 12:32:51'),
('111111111111','GRAY','2021-04-15 13:21:10'),
('111111111111','GOLD','2019-11-11 08:14:11'),
('111111111112','GRAY','2021-06-10 12:32:51'),
('111111111112','GRAY','2021-04-15 13:21:10'),
('111111111113','SILVER','2021-06-10 12:32:51'),
('111111111113','GRAY','2021-04-15 13:21:10'),
('111111111113','SILVER','2019-11-11 08:14:11');
```

**expected result:**

```
|       id   |item  |auditdate          |result
|111111111111|GRAY  |2021-06-10 12:32:51|
|111111111111|GRAY  |2021-04-15 13:21:10|
|111111111111|GOLD  |2019-11-11 08:14:11|Different
|111111111112|GRAY  |2021-06-10 12:32:51|
|111111111112|GRAY  |2021-04-15 13:21:10|
|111111111113|SILVER|2021-06-10 12:32:51|
|111111111113|GRAY  |2021-04-15 13:21:10|different
|111111111113|SILVER|2021-06-10 12:32:51|
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `Select` statement. Try this. May not be a good code but shows your prefered result.

***Logic : Count grouped by id and item and displays `different` if count=1.***

```
SELECT *, 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temptable_test WHERE t.`id`=id AND t.`item`=item)=1, 'Different', '') AS result 
FROM temptable_test t;
```

**Result**

```
id            item    auditdate            result     
------------  ------  -------------------  -----------
111111111111  GRAY    2021-06-10 12:32:51             
111111111111  GRAY    2021-04-15 13:21:10             
111111111111  GOLD    2019-11-11 08:14:11  Different  
111111111112  GRAY    2021-06-10 12:32:51             
111111111112  GRAY    2021-04-15 13:21:10             
111111111113  SILVER  2021-06-10 12:32:51             
111111111113  GRAY    2021-04-15 13:21:10  Different  
111111111113  SILVER  2019-11-11 08:14:11
```

**To show the different items only try**

```
SELECT * FROM temptable_test t WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temptable_test WHERE t.`id`=id AND t.`item`=item)=1;
```

**Result**

```
id            item    auditdate            
------------  ------  ---------------------
111111111111  GOLD    2019-11-11 08:14:11  
111111111113  GRAY    2021-04-15 13:21:10
```

Comment: Thank you @ErrBon. what if the result would be only the differentthat will be shown?   sample.  111111111111  | Gold|2019-11-11 08:14:11.

Comment: @Jon check my answer I included it to show the different items only

Comment: @Jon Kindly mark answer as accepted if it satisfy your question. Thank you